# Aviso: un input no debería cambiar de no controlado a controlado (o viceversa)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

No consigo quitar este Warning en un formulario con un input de tipo checkbox.

> Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type checkbox to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component

Mi código:

```
<div className="col-md-3">
  <div className="form-row">
    <div className="form-unit">
      <label style={{ minWidth: width, textAlign: 'center' }}>Promote:</label>
      <div className="form-row">
        <div className="form-unit" style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
          {this.state.mixinEnvironments.length > 0 && this.state.mixinEnvironments.map((envPr, idx) => {
            if (this.state.promoteEnvironments.includes(envPr)) {
              return <label key={'envPr_' + idx}><li className="badge badge-info" style={{ listStyle: 'none' }} value={envPr}>
              </li>
                <input name={envPr} className="badgebox" type="checkbox" id="info" checked={this.state.fv.environmentsPromote.value.indexOf(envPr) >= 0}></input>
                <span style={{ border: '1px solid #ccc', cursor: 'not-allowed', backgroundColor: '#eeeeee' }} className="fa-stack fa-lg badge-size">
                  <i className="fa fa-check text-success fa-stack-1x badgecheck"></i>
                </span>
              </label>
            } else {
              return <label key={'envPr_' + idx}><li className="badge badge-info" style={{ listStyle: 'none', cursor: 'pointer' }} value={envPr}>
              </li>
                <input name={envPr} className="badgebox" disabled={true} type="checkbox" id="info"></input>
                <span style={{ border: '1px solid #ccc', cursor: 'not-allowed', backgroundColor: '#eeeeee' }} className="fa-stack fa-lg badge-size">
                  <i className="fa fa-check text-success fa-stack-1x badgecheck"></i>
                </span>
              </label>
            }
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Me indica que el error es en el input:

```
<input name={envPr} className="badgebox" type="checkbox" id="info" checked={this.state.fv.environmentsPromote.value.indexOf(envPr) >= 0}></input>
```

Poniendo defaultChecked en lugar de checked se soluciona pero deja de funcionar como se espera.

Answer (score 0):

En general esa advertencia es mostrada cuando no estás seteando un valor inicial para el input del componente y luego sí le ingresas algo. 
Para tu caso, no me lo explico del todo, ya que `this.state.fv.environmentsPromote.value.indexOf(envPr) >= 0` creo que debería en cualquier instancia retornarte `true` o `false`, independiente del valor que pueda venir en la primera parte de la comparación.
Podrías probar a imprimir en consola, al inicio del render, cuales son los valores que está tomando la condición puesta en tu `checked`. Otra cosa que podrías probar es hacer una doble negación, algo como:

```
checked={!!this.state.fv.environmentsPromote.value.indexOf(envPr) >= 0}
```